# The greatest common divisor of two positive integers python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def mike(a,b):
    d=min(a,b)
    e=d
    if max(a,b)%d==0 and e%d==0:
        return d
    else:
        return mike(max(a,b),d-1)
print(mike(12,18))
```

I cannot find a way to have the value of 'e' as a fixed value of the minimum among the two integers, which in case is 12. As the code moves on so does the value of 'e'. But I want it to have a fixed value of the least among the two. Sorry for the noob question. Help please.

Comment: In Python 3, you can just use `math.gcd(a,b)` to get the gcd.  Or did you want to write your own version?

Comment: `e%d==0` is always `true`.

Comment: Use [global variable](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)?

Comment: Using `d-1` doesn't really make sense.  Consider `gcd(12, 7)`.  This will recurse with `gcd(12, 6)` which is 6, when the answer should be 1.

Comment: @TomKarzes I was trying the recursive version of gcd. I had it done using iterative function and wanted to try using recursion.

Comment: Well, the standard way to do it is:  `return b if a == 0 else mike(b % a, a)`

Comment: @TomKarzes that's why I'm asking for the value of 'e' to be a fixed one having the least among the two. i'm asking for a way to do that.

Comment: If you want it to be recursive, and want to fix `e` to be the minimum of the two on the initial call, never changing it, then you need two functions.  The initial one can pass `e` to the second one as the first argument, and the second function can just keep passing it to itself unchanged.  I don't know why you want that, but presumably that would work.  I don't think you're going to find the gcd that way though.

Comment: (1) I just explained how to do it, and (2) you won't be able to calculate gcd that way, unless you pass it as a third argument that serves no purpose.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you set e=d and why you need d-1 in recursion

```
def mike(a,b):
    rest = max(a, b) % min(a, b)
    if rest == 0:
        return min(a, b)
    else:
        return mike(min(a, b), rest)
```

Calc of gcd.

(48,30)

Divide the biggest by the lowest and get the rest.
48 / 30 = 1 (rest 18)

Divide the previous divisor by the rest 
30 / 18 = 1 (rest 12)

Divide the previous divisor by the rest again
18 / 12 = 1 (rest 6)

Divide the previous divisor by the rest again
12 / **6** = 2 (rest 0)

gcd is the divisor when rest == 0

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need to funcions, you can just add e as an optional argument

```
def mike(a,b,e=None):
    d=min(a,b)
    if not e:
        e=d
    if max(a,b)%d==0 and e%d==0:
    return d,e
    else:
        return mike(max(a,b),d-1,e)
print(mike(12,18))
```

That way you can call it recursively, and still track and output the minimum of the original function

Comment: Indent "return d,e" and why return 2 values?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it at 8 am pre coffee.  It needs a lot of edits, and the return e was showing the result.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did this at the end. Thanks for all the answers though. I know I made it a way more complicated.

```
def mike(x,y):
    e=min(x,y)
    def mi(a,b):
        d=min(a,b)
        if max(a,b)%d==0 and e%d==0:
            return d
        else:
            return mi(max(a,b),d-1)
    zz=mi(x,y)
    return zz

print(mike(12,18))
```